# Keras LSTM model for binary classification with sequences

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow, time-series

I'm currently working on a bigger project.
**The goal is to automatically find split points in time series which splits the series into elementary patterns.**

I have a lot of training data in form of time series with **different lengths** and split points manually recorded on useful positions.
Basically, I have the `x`, `y`, `z` positions and the distances between those points over a centered window of the lengths 2, 25 and 50 (`dist2`, `dist25`, `dist50`). I also divided the room into a 3D grid and figured out in which cell the position lies (`cell_x`, `cell_y`, `cell_z`). I think this could be useful because elementary operations will more likely be in one or two cells.

[image: Fig1]

[image: Fig2]
cell_x, cell_y, cell_z based on size 50. The vertical red lines are the split points of the training data.

**Now I want to know at every point in the time series if it is a split point or not.**

In my opinion, these are enough features to start with but I think my Keras model isn't correct because the result is always and only 1 at the 0's time series index. It's basically, a binary classification problem based on past and future values. This was the reason I've tried to solve it with an **LSTM**. It looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape = (None, input_dim), return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(20))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer='adam',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Because I'm at the very beginning of the whole Machine Learning topic and the mass of materials is a bit overwhelming I'm here to ask for some help. I know that there are a lot of other things (bad training data, wrong features, wrong parameters, ...) which can cause to this results but I want to know how I can build a Keras model for this problem correctly. I already found a lot of Keras examples but I'm not sure if they fit the problem.

Example of data: Features and label of one record: [gist.github.com/chryb/2b3312b0ab640a1f28c8cb2d3dbbd86e](http://gist.github.com/chryb/2b3312b0ab640a1f28c8cb2d3dbbd86e) | The column is_keyframe represents the labels for each index. Based on a Stackoverflow question I transformed the data with the following to the right LSTM input format: [gist.github.com/chryb/3de34ba44488012bf79ff4c51a2a43ae](http://gist.github.com/chryb/3de34ba44488012bf79ff4c51a2a43ae)